# Interacting with ssh-keygen through c#

Tags: c#, process, exe

I want to call ssh-keygen in c# to execute the command like this:

[image: result gif]

And I made a few attempts to use the **Process** class and **StandardInput**. But ssh-keygen doesn't receive the incoming stream of **StandardInput**.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var process = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-keygen.exe",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    Arguments= "-t rsa -b 4096 -C test"
                }
            };

            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
                ((Process)sender).StandardInput.WriteLine("test");
            };

            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
            };

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

            process.WaitForExit();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

[image: failure result gif]

**NOTE**:

I want to know why **StandardInput** doesn't work and how to interact with it.

Comment: [Related](https://superuser.com/questions/478798/running-ssh-keygen-without-human-interaction/478799)